# Как следовать за текстом при переполнении?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**Вопрос:** Пользователь сам вводит текст в моё отображение `Text()`, но когда textView переполняется, мне необходимо дальше следовать за текстом, который вводит пользователь.
Как возможно это реализовать?

Comment: Это как вообще. Как он вводит в Text(). Так то TextField по умолчанию следует за текстом